# getting error: get() returned more than one objects ( using get_object_or_404)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm getting error get() returned more than one Subtitle_name ..it returned !by executing simple update view using django.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from .models import Subtitle_name
def updating_subtitle_name(request):
    obj=get_object_or_404(Subtitle_name)
    form=update_Subtitle_name_Form(request.POST or None,instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context={
        "form":form,
        "subtitle_name_id":f"Update{obj.subtitle_name_id}"
        }
    return render(request,'update_subtitle_name.html',context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Subtitle_name
class update_Subtitle_name_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Subtitle_name
        fields=['subtitle_name_id','subtitle_name','subtitle_short_code']
        def update_subtitle(self,*args,**kwargs):
            instance=self.instance
            subtitle_name_id=self.cleaned_data.get('subtitle_name_id')
            print(subtitle_name_id)
qs=Subtitle_name.object.filter(subtitle_name_iexact=subtitle_name_id)
            if instance is not None:
                qs=qs.exclude(pk=instance.pk)
            if qs.exist():
                raise forms.ValidationError("This title has already been used Please insert new value")
            return subtitle_name_id
```

**update_subtitle_name.html**

`<form method="POST">{%csrf_token%}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>`

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /update_subtitle_name_create/ get()
>   returned more than one Subtitle_name -- it returned 62!

Comment: you need to pass some value for lookup, like `get_object_or_404(Subtitle_name, field=some_value)` to get the object.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Subtitle_name, pk=1)
```

Comment: how can i make it dynamic to `forms.py`

Comment: do you post `pk` from html form

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404` internally calls the queryset that is `all()` query so if you are passing the `Subtitle_name` it expects filter criteria as keyword arguments like this `queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)` if your are passing no keyword argument is is returning all instances of `Subtitle_name`. And `get` method will always raise error if more than one object is matched with the filtering criteria. It is capable of returning only one object. If you want to load more that one objects in criteria you should call `filter()` on queryset.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. Lets fix them one by one:

First, you need to pass which `Subtitle_name` you want to update. You can send that value to view by `urls`, for example:

```
# urls
path('subtitle/update/<int:pk>/', views.updating_subtitle_name, name="subtitle_update_view")
```

Now, you need to capture the value of `pk` from url to view:

```
def updating_subtitle_name(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Subtitle_name, pk)
    form = update_Subtitle_name_Form(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    # please use CamelCase when defining class name ie `update_Subtitle_name_Form` should be `UpdateSubtitleNameForm`
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {
        "form":form,
        "subtitle_name_id":f"Update{obj.subtitle_name_id}"
    }
    return render(request,'update_subtitle_name.html',context)
```

Finally, you don't need to use `def update_subtitle(self,*args,**kwargs):` method. When you pass `instance` keyword argument with form initialization, then the form will update that object only.